# Why is my mint plant drying out?

Tags: houseplants, watering, leaves, mint

[image]

My mint plant (bought about 2 months back) is drying and the leaves are going brown.  The stems have fallen to the sides as well. I dried it out a few times and changed its position but I'm not sure if it's a problem of inadequate watering or light. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Mint likes moist soil and will tolerate shade ([ref](http://www.almanac.com/plant/mint)) so if the plant were mine I would cut back the unsightly part and then dunk the entire pot in a bucket of water for an hour or so. Then drain off the surplus, return to cache-pot and wait for fresh shoots - which should not take long (if all goes well!) as it grows fast (["four inches per month"](http://homeguides.sfgate.com/fast-mint-spread-87205.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Put it outside, don't water it anymore.